# Accelerator Key Not Displaying for a form application in Windows Server 2008 R2

Tags: c#, winforms

### Problem Information

Accleerator Key (Underline) not displayed in Windows Server 2008 R2 for a form application.

I have created a form application in .Net 3.5, VS 2013 (in windows 8 OS).

The Scenario is as follows
There is a split container in the form and split container contains a label
Label name : &Test.

Accleerator Key T is displayed in Windows 7 / 8 but not in Windows Server 2008 R2.

But, if the label is placed outside the splitcontainer, the acclertaor key is displayed. (There is no issues)

It will be very helpful if anyone can share information regarding the problem.